# Ensure that process started by COM connection is killed

Tags: python, python-2.7, com, win32com, minitab

I'm automating Minitab 17 using Python's `win32com` library, and while all of commands execute correctly, I can't seem to get the process started by the Minitab process to exit when my script ends.  My structure looks like

```
from myapi import get_data

import pythoncom
from win32com.client import gencache

def process_data(data):
    # In case of threading
    pythoncom.CoInitialize()
    app = gencache.EnsureDispatch('Mtb.Application')
    try:
        # do some processing
        pass
    finally:
        # App-specific command that is supposed to close the software
        app.Quit()
        # Ensure the object is released
        del mtb
        # In case of threading
        pythoncom.CoUninitialize()

def main():
    data = get_data()
    process_data(data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I don't get any exceptions raised or error messages printed, the `Mtb.exe` process is still listed in task manager.  Even more frustrating is if I run the following in an IPython session:

```
>>> from win32com.client import gencache
>>> app = gencache.EnsureDispatch('Mtb.Application')
>>> ^D
```

The Minitab process is closed immediately.  I observe the same behavior in a normal `python` interactive session.  <strike>Why would the process get closed correctly when running in an interactive session but not in a standalone script?  What is done differently there that isn't being performed in my script?</strike>

I've also tried running `process_data` in a `threading.Thread` and in a `multiprocessing.Process` with no luck.

**EDIT:**

If I have a script containing nothing but

```
from win32com.client import gencache
app = gencache.EnsureDispatch('Mtb.Application')
```

then when I run it I see the `Mtb.exe` process in task manager, but once the script exits the process is killed.  So instead my question is why does it matter if this COM object is declared at top-level vs. inside a function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the the garbage collector could clean up the reference to the underlying `IUnknown` object (the base type for all COM objects), and without the gc doing it's job the process stayed alive.  I solve the problem by using the `weakref` module to immediately wrap the COM object in a weakref so it could be more easily deferenced:

```
from myapi import get_data

import weakref
from win32com.client import gencache
import pythoncom

def process_data(mtb_ref, data):
    try:
        mtb_ref().do_something(data)
    finally:
        mtb_ref().Quit()

def main(mtb_ref):
    data = get_data()
    process_data(mtb_ref, data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pythoncom.CoInitialize()
    mtb_ref = weakref.ref(gencache.EnsureDispatch('Mtb.Application'))
    main(mtb_ref)
    pythoncom.CoUninitialize()
```

I'm not sure I understand fully why this makes a difference, but I believe it's because there's never a direct reference to the object, only a weak reference, so all the functions that use the COM object only do so indirectly, allowing the GC to know that the object can be collected sooner.  For whatever reason it still needs to be created at the top level of the module, but this at least makes it possible for me to write more reusable code that cleanly exits.

Comment: I have never had to use a weakref with win32com app. Something else is going on. I just extended my solution, please try and let me know if that works.

Comment: @Schollii I tried something very much like that while coming to the solution I've posted.  If I pass in the `mtb` object without `weakref` then it doesn't close, but if I do use `weakref` I can pass it around fine.  I also tried declaring it with a `weakref` inside the function that I want to use it in, but for whatever reason the GC immediately cleaned it up and the ref only returned `None`.

Comment: The details matter, please try exactly what I put

Answer (score 2):

I don't have minitab so I can't verify but try forcing a shutdown of COM server by setting app = None just after the call to app.Quit? Python uses ref counting to manage object life cycle, so assuming there are no other refs to app then setting it to none should cause it to be finalized immediately. I have seen that cause similar issues. You should not need weak reference, something else is going on. The following, based on your answer, should work:

```
def process_data(mtb, data):
    try:
        mtb.do_something(data)
    finally:
        mtb.Quit()

def main(mtb):
    data = get_data()
    process_data(mtb, data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pythoncom.CoInitialize()
    mtb = gencache.EnsureDispatch('Mtb.Application')
    main(mtb)
    mtb.Quit()
    mtb = None
    pythoncom.CoUninitialize()
```

Comment: I'll give it a try tomorrow morning

Comment: Nope, no change in behavior =/

Comment: I figured out how to do it, though!  I'll post it as an answer here so you can see it too, I only figured it out through a combination of `gc.set_debug(gc.DEBUG_LEAK)` and the `dis` module, it seems pretty specific but I imagine it could be useful for other COM objects.

Answer (score 0):

after pythoncom.CoUninitialize()  i still see process
for me it help ([based](https://www.mail-archive.com/python-win32@python.org/msg09749.html)):

```py
from comtypes.automation import IDispatch
from ctypes import c_void_p, cast, POINTER, byref

def release_reference(self, obj):
    logger.debug("release com object")
    oleobj = obj._oleobj_
    addr = int(repr(oleobj).split()[-1][2:-1], 16)

    pointer = POINTER(IDispatch)()
    cast(byref(pointer), POINTER(c_void_p))[0] = addr
    pointer.Release()
```